# floppy0: no floppy controllers found

Tags: drivers, floppy

I am currently trying some Ubuntu-Server based projects and want to use some floppies for it. But after installing Ubuntu-server16.04 LTS on my machine, I got an error on start-up:

```
floppy0: no floppy controllers found
```

But I can't solve the problem... afaik there could be an kernel error, but I just started using Ubuntu and am just at the beginning.

Comment: Do you have a floppy controller?

Comment: i think so - ive build in a floppy drive and connected it with IDE-Cable

Comment: `vi /etc/modprobe.d/aliases`, find the line `alias block-major-2` and comment it, or manually add the line(if it does not have) `alias block-major-2 off` and reboot. There is an ancient question at Ubuntu launchpad that nobody seems to care about the subject - https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+question/155343

Comment: The `/etc/modprobe.d/aliases` got me no file, so had to create it and just added the line. But this didn't work, the problem is still occuring

Comment: Does your motherboard have a floppy drive connector (it's a [34-pin connector](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/flopcabl.htm) and is smaller in size than an IDE connector)? If you managed to plug an IDE cable into a floppy disk drive, it shouldn't have fit very well!

Comment: Yes, of course! I got the floppy drive ribbon cable connected with the FDD and the Motherboard. I also tried to rotate the ribbon cable at the FDD, but this only appears to let the Drive go crazy and spin all over once you've inserted a disk :/

Answer (score 3):

1. `sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks.rules` (in my Xubuntu 16.04 - `80-udisks2.rules`)
2. search strings and replace them with `0` to `1`

`# PC floppy drives
 #
 KERNEL=="fd*", ENV{ID_DRIVE_FLOPPY}="0"`

`# USB floppy drives
 #
 SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="08", 
 ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="04", ENV{ID_DRIVE_FLOPPY}="0"`

3. Create folger

`sudo mkdir /media/floppy`

`sudo chmod 777 /media/floppy`

4. `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`
5. add a line to the end:

`/dev/fd0 /media/floppy auto rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0 0`

6. `sudo gedit /etc/modules`
7. add a line to the end:

`floppy`

8. then either reboot the system or perform

`sudo modprobe floppy`

**Edit:** I supplemented my answer

- check if the floppy module is loaded:

`lsmod | grep -i floppy`

If it returns `floppy` then you have the floppy module loaded

- load the floppy module:

`sudo modprobe -v floppy`

`lsmod | grep -i floppy`

- Try adding your username in the floppy group:

`sudo adduser $USER floppy`

- Try

`udisks --mount /dev/fd0`

PS. Floppy WILL NOT auto launch a window when inserted, they were made before that! You will need to go to `nautilus` and double click on it. You need to unmount before inserting a new floppy disk. Your next floppy you insert won't mount.

- another way:

`udisks --mount /dev/fd0`

**if not at all** - try to install `fdutils`

and `fdmount` seems useful. Try: `sudo fdmount -l`

*more ways I do not know and have not tried:)*

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I did what you said, except for the first path (I installed udisks2 already), but in the end `modprobe floppy`gets me the following error: `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'floppy': No such device`

Comment: I got the feeling, that either a controller is not working proberly or I connected it in a wrong way..?

Comment: I supplemented my answer

Comment: thank you. fdmount says: drive fd0 does not exist... I think, my Problem is on another level than mounting it. Although I want to thank you! (didnt know fdutils till now)

Answer (score 3):

After I tried all your suggestions yesterday, I finally found an entry in my BIOS, which said: `Floppy Legacy: Disabled`. Changed it to `1.44 MB`, now everything is fine.